# how to count the amount of sentences in a paragraph in python

Tags: python

this is what i have so far but my pparagraph only contains 5 full stops therefore only 5 sentences.but it keeps on returning 14 as a answer. can anyone help??

```
file = open ('words.txt', 'r')
lines= list (file)
file_contents = file.read()
print(lines)
file.close()
words_all = 0
for line in lines:
    words_all = words_all + len(line.split())
    print ('Total words:   ', words_all)
full_stops = 0
for stop in lines:
    full_stops = full_stops + len(stop.split('.'))
print ('total stops:    ', full_stops)
```

here is the txt file

A Turning machine is a device that manipulates symbols on a strip of tape 
according to a table of rules. Despite its simplicity, a Turing machine can be
adapted to simulate the logic of any computer algorithm, and is particularly
useful in explaining the functions of a CPU inside a computer. The "Turing"
machine was described by Alan Turing in 1936, who called it an
"a(utomatic)-machine". The Turing machine is not intended as a practical
computing technology, but rather as a hypothetical device representing a
computing machine. Turing machines help computer scientists understand
the limits of mechaniacl computation.

Comment: You are counting the parts *between* the full stops. Why not use `stop.count('.')` instead?

Comment: can you post the words.txt content as well?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Not only the segments between periods, but also between newlines and periods.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters counting the dots is not always a good practice to count the sentences - i.e.: "This bar weighs 0.5 kg and measures 1.2 m."

Comment: @drekyn: Sure, but the OP is making things a little worse still. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a line doesn't contain a period, `split` will return a single element: the line itself:

```
>>> "asdasd".split('.')
    ['asdasd']
```

So you're counting the number of lines plus the number of periods. Why are you splitting the file to lines at all?

```
with open('words.txt', 'r') as file:
    file_contents = file.read()

    print('Total words:   ', len(file_contents.split()))
    print('total stops:    ', file_contents.count('.'))
```

Comment: This won't work if your sentences have abbreviations.

Answer (score 9):

Easiest way of doing it would be:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

sentences = 'A Turning machine is a device that manipulates symbols on a strip of tape according to a table of rules. Despite its simplicity, a Turing machine can be adapted to simulate the logic of any computer algorithm, and is particularly useful in explaining the functions of a CPU inside a computer. The "Turing" machine was described by Alan Turing in 1936, who called it an "a(utomatic)-machine". The Turing machine is not intended as a practical computing technology, but rather as a hypothetical device representing a computing machine. Turing machines help computer scientists understand the limits of mechaniacl computation.'

number_of_sentences = sent_tokenize(sentences)

print(len(number_of_sentences))
```

Output:

```
5
```

Comment: Does this work for any language?

Comment: Only python as the OP mentions in the tag/title

Answer (score 6):

Use regex.

```
In [13]: import re
In [14]: par  = "This is a paragraph? So it is! Ok, there are 3 sentences."
In [15]: re.split(r'[.!?]+', par)
Out[15]: ['This is a paragraph', ' So it is', ' Ok, there are 3 sentences', '']
```

Comment: remember to handle cases with "..." sentence endings. Perhaps by first replacing them with single "."

Comment: It won't work if your sentences have abbreviations.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
print "total stops: ", open('words.txt', 'r').read().count(".")
```

Details:

```
with open("words.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()
    print "total stops: ", data.count(".")
```

Comment: In OPs code `file_contents` is empty, the file was already read by itearting over it inside `list`.